# css - table row background color fill all padding space

Tags: css

I have an html table that looks like this:

```
<table style="border-spacing: 10px">
 <tr style='background-color:red'>
  <td><b>Member</b></td>
  <td><b>Account #</b></td>
  <td><b>Site</b></td>
  <td><b>Date</b></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The padding in between the  elements is fine, but the background color seems to only fill the TDs and leave lots of gaps because of padding/spacing. How can I make the TR background color fill the entire row, and flow through the 10px border spacing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `border-collapse:collapse;` to collapse the gaps and add any padding you need with:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 8px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4EzM3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Apply the background on the `table` not on the `tr`:

```
<table style="border-spacing: 10px; background-color:red;">
 <tr style=''>
  <td><b>Member</b></td>
  <td><b>Account #</b></td>
  <td><b>Site</b></td>
  <td><b>Date</b></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/C7NBy/

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following things:

1)HTML+CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    /*this is by default value of border-collapse property*/
    border-spacing: 0px;
    /*this will remove unneccessary white space between table cells and between table cell and table border*/
}
th,td
{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Member</b></td>
            <td><b>Account #</b></td>
            <td><b>Site</b></td>
            <td><b>Date</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Or,

2) HTML+CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td
{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Member</b></td>
            <td><b>Account #</b></td>
            <td><b>Site</b></td>
            <td><b>Date</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you need to make all the table entries bold, you can do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td
{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Member</td>
            <td>Account #</td>
            <td>Site</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```